# Using Pandas change yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss-07:00 to Pacific time with no time zone being displayed

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have about 400k rows in a pandas dataframe column that look like this:

Column 1   |   Column 2

0      |      2019-05-07T02:00:16-07:00

I would really like to convert the above date and time to Pacific time in the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format (without the 07:00 switching to Pacific Time's equivalent.

I tried removing the T and replacing it with a space using str.replace() but then when I try to use tz_convert it doesn't recognize it as a datetime object.

tried using the code below but none works I either get an error "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values," or in the case of below lambda the code runs, thinks it changed it to Pacific time but the time remains the same.

```
df['created'] = df['created'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).tz_convert('US/Pacific'))

df['created'] = df['created'].dt.tz_convert('US/Pacific')
```

Please help me solve this

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.Column2.str[:-6])
`

Comment: okay, that was a step forward. Could you tell me how to convert this to Pacific time?

Comment: Isn't it already pacific time: `pd.to_datetime("2019-05-07T02:00:16-07:00").astimezone('US/Pacific')`

Comment: So you need to know what is original timezone of your data

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot WeNyoBen and cronburg. Someone just told me it was in UTC and I blindly believed that and did not check. This solves all my current problems!

Edit1: how do I mark this as answered and can give you some sort of recognition